# How to reorder facet_wrap based on two variables

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, facet-wrap

I need to make a bar plot based on two variables (`points` and `type`) with fill.

Below is a minimal example, I would like to see the points ***ranking by guard points*** and ***ranking by points as guard or forward***.

I tried `~reorder(names, -c(type, points))` but it doesn't work.

```
    name <- c("James Harden","James Harden","Lebron James","Lebron James","Lebron James","Kawhi Leonerd","Kawhi Leonerd","Klay Thompson","Steph Curry","Kevin Durant","Kevin Durant","Chris Paul","Chris Paul")
    team <- c("HOU","OKC","LAL","MIA","CLE","SAS","TOR","GSW","GSW","GSW","OKC","HOU","LAC")
    points <- c(2000,12000,2000,10000,20000,7000,2000,14000,20000,6000,18000,4000,14000)
    type <- c("G","G","F","G","F","G","G","G","G","F","F","G","G")
    nba <- data.frame(name,team,points,type)
    nba <- nba %>% arrange(desc(type))
    ggplot(nba, aes(x = type, y = points, fill = team)) +
      geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack', color = 'black') +
      facet_wrap(~reorder(name,-points),  ncol = 1, strip.position = "top") +
      coord_flip() + theme_minimal() +
      labs(x = "players", y = "points", title = "Rank by points as Guard")
```

If it's ranked by points as guard, I would like to see `Steph Curry` ranks top, `Chris Paul` at second, `James Harden` and `Klay` tied at third, `Lebron` at fifth, `Kawhi` at sixth, and `KD` at the bottom.

If it's ranked by points as either guard or forward, I'd like to see `Lebron` at top, `KD` second, so on and so forth.

Comment: It's not random! look at the results of ```reorder(nba$name,-nba$points)```

Comment: @M-M maybe I'm dull but it doesn't seem to change anything for me.  And if I remembered correctly, you don't really need to attach the dataset name in ggplot

Comment: I meant to look at it outside of `ggplot` Levels are based on `-points`

Comment: @M-M Interesting, in what ways can I change that order though?

Comment: `facet_wrap(~reorder(name, -points, sum)`? You are using the average points per category (team and position) for each player, which isn't very informative.

Comment: @Axeman This answers one of the questions, thank you so much! any comments on ranking by points for a specific type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort it for points as guard by adding a helper column. Look below;

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

nba %>% 
 mutate(guardpoints = points * (type=="G")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = type, y = points, fill = team)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack', color = 'black') +
  facet_wrap(~reorder(name, -guardpoints, sum),  ncol = 1, strip.position = "top") +
  coord_flip() + theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = "players", y = "points", title = "Rank by points as Guard")
```

[image]

```r
nba %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = type, y = points, fill = team)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack', color = 'black') +
  facet_wrap(~reorder(name, -points, sum),  ncol = 1, strip.position = "top") +
  coord_flip() + theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = "players", y = "points", title = "Rank by points")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-06-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>